# Polar Form in Complex Numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

I've recently started getting in touch with complex numbers and I found it is quite easier to operate with them (multiplication, division, powers) in polar form rather than algebraically developing the whole thing. Would it be recommended? The main problem I'm having is that as I'm computing the angles with the calculator, it sometimes approximates angles and therefore some results which could be written as a fraction (for example, $5^{1/2}/2$), are given in a decimal (approximated) way. Any tip to work this out with the lesser error possible?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Depending on how complicated your expressions are you could work without a calculator if you are looking to get rid of any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: *don't* compute the angles with a calculator. Why would you want to do that? For instance, if you want to compute$$\left(4\left(\cos\left(\frac34\right)+\sin\left(\frac34\right)i\right)\right)\times\left(3\left(\cos\left(\frac23\right)+\sin\left(\frac23\right)i\right)\right),$$then you will just get$$12\left(\cos\left(\frac{17}{12}\right)+\sin\left(\frac{17}{12}\right)i\right).$$No need to compute those sines and cosines.

Comment: The problem is when transforming from conventional notation (i. e.: 2+5i) to angle notation (√29 ∠ arctan(5/2)). For example, in the operation (3+2i)/(4-3i), I'd operate (√13∠arctan(2/3))/(5∠arctan(3/4)); and the result: (√13)/5(cos(arctan(2/3)-arctan(3/4))+sin(arctan(2/3)-arctan(3/4))i). Should I maintain those angles just as arctan then? Is there any better way to do that which I don't know?

Comment: Yes, mantain it like that.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could write, for instance, $\cos1$ instead of the approximation.  Or $re^{i\theta}=r\cos\theta+ir\sin\theta$, using Euler's formula, in general.